# What is this date format? 1,539,352,380

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, datetime

I'm using a Postgresql database. The date field only shows values similar to 1,539,352,380.

What is this format and how would I convert it to regular mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Is the date field actually a `date` type or something else?

Answer (score 3):

This number looks like an epoch timestamp, that is the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970.

In Postgres, you can turn it to a timestamp with `to_timestamp()`:

```
select to_timestamp(1539352380::bigint)
```

Or you can use explicit date arithmetics:

```
select date '1970-01-01' + 1539352380 * interval '1 second'
```

This gives `2018-10-12 13:53:00`. That is a `timestamp` datatype. If you want to format it to a given *string* format, use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp(1539352380::bigint), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```